# Using TIdCompressorLib to Decompress gzip file

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using Delphi 2007 with Indy 10.  I have a gzip file.  I have verified it can be decompressed with this [Online Decompression Tool](http://online.b1.org/online).

I am trying to use the **TIdCompressorZlib** component to decompress using Delphi.  Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lCompressor : TIdCompressorZLib;
  FileStream : TFileStream;
  memorystream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  lCompressor := TIdCompressorZLib.create(self);
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\test.gz', fmOpenRead);
  filestream.position := 0;
  memorystream:= TMemoryStream.create;
  memorystream.position := 0;
  lcompressor.DecompressGZipStream(FileStream,MemoryStream);
  filestream.free;
  showmessage('done');
end;
```

I cannot get it to work.  If I pass **fmOpenReadWrite** in the constructor I get a **zlib error (-5)** when DecompressGZipStream is called.

If I pass **fmOpenRead** in the constructor I get a **OS System Error Code 5 Access Denied** when DecompressGZipStream is called.

**Update**  David Hefferan suggested it is a file reading issue.  So I am zeroing in on that.  I am able to copy the file using this procedure:

```
Procedure FileCopy( Const sourcefilename, targetfilename: String );
Var
 S, T: TFileStream;
Begin
 S := TFileStream.Create( sourcefilename, fmOpenRead );
 try
   T := TFileStream.Create( targetfilename,
                            fmOpenWrite or fmCreate );
   try
     T.CopyFrom(S, S.Size ) ;
   finally
     T.Free;
   end;
 finally
   S.Free;
 end;
 showmessage('done');
End;
```

**UPD**  Per David Heffernan, I have verified I can Read the data.  I successfully ran the file through the following function.  It returns the proper number of characters (bytes):

```
function GetTextFromFile(AFile: string; var Returnstring: string): Boolean;
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(AFile) then Exit;
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFile, fmOpenRead);
  try
    if FileStream.Size <> 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(Returnstring, FileStream.Size);
      FileStream.Read(Returnstring[1], FileStream.Size);
      Result := True;
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Access denied error code 5 is not ambiguous. Put the zlib to one side and try to read the file stream. Do you get the same error. As for read/write, why do you want to write?

Comment: Not following by what you mean "put the zlib to one side".  Do you mean "put aside compression - are you able to read the file"?  As for "why do you want to write" - no I don't want to write to the same file.  I was just experimenting.  And found by changing the TFileStream open attribute things changed.  I will verify I can read the file.  In the end I just want a simple routine to take a gz file and decompress it to text.

Comment: Error indicates that you can't read the file. Because access is denied. Which makes this not a zlib issue. Try to read from the file stream.

Comment: Not exactly answer to you question, just FYI: Delphi zlib unit is able to compress/decompress gzip files. Normally it deals with zlib stream (practically no header), but if you use version of constructor with WindowBits=15+16, it will. 16 (or should we say, 4th bit) means to use gzip header, 15 is good value for WindowBits itself.

Comment: @YuriyAfanasenkov - ok - will give it a try.  I see system.zlib.dcu.  But no pas file so that I could see what methods are available.  Could you furnish simple example?  I am using Delphi 2007 by the way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am able to read and copy the file using the procedure "FileCopy"

Comment: Try to read from the file stream like I said. I. The same context as the code in question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - sorry I am not understanding what you mean by "try to read from the file stream".  I thought by using the **FileCopy** routine I referenced it would implicitly read the data stream.  Is this not the case?  Is Delphi actually not reading the stream but only doing OS operations (i.e. copy the file).  I will look for examples of reading a TFileStream.

Comment: Call ReadBuffer to read from a stream. Do it in the same context as the code that fails.

Comment: Would **FileStream.Read** accomplish the same?  See new function I just added.

Comment: The code fails with `fmOpenRead` because `DecompressGZipStream` tries to overwrite the gzip header in the *source* stream before decompressing it! I have no idea why, I didn't write that code, but I will look into rewriting it to not modify the source stream anymore. In the meantime, if you send me the gzip file, I'll look into the zlib error. Although, I did just recently make some zlib logic updates, so check if the problem still occurs with the latest Indy snapshot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks as always for your expert knowledge of Indy.  I downloaded Indy10_5366.zip from Fulgan site but it still throws the same Access Denied error.  I will send you version of the file.  Thanks.

Comment: @MSchenkel I already explained why you are getting an access denied error. `fmOpenRead` opens the file for read-only access, but `DecompressGZipStream()` writes to the source stream. It can't write to a read-only file. My comment about getting the latest snapshot was in reference to seeing if the zlib -5 error was fixed or not.

Comment: Yes - trying fmOpenReadWrite gives the zlib -5 error.

Comment: @MSchenkel: then either the gzip file is corrupted, or Indy is not processing it with zlib correctly. Either way, you can send me the file and I will look into it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Delphi `zlib` unit to decompress gzip.

Sample code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DecompressionStream : TDecompressionStream;
  FileStream : TFileStream;
  dest: TFileStream;
  byteCount: Integer;
  buffer: array [0..65535] of Byte;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\test.gz', fmOpenRead);
  try
    //no need to set FileStream position to 0, it's there already

    DecompressionStream:=TDecompressionStream.Create(FileStream, 15+16);

    //16 is flag that gzip stream used, not zlib.
    //15 is maximum memory usage, to speed-up decompression. 
    try
      dest:=TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\test.txt', fmCreate);
      try
        dest.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream,0);
      finally
        dest.free;
      end;
    finally
      DecompressionStream.free;
    end;
  finally
    filestream.free;
  end;
  showmessage('done');
end;
```

**UPD**: this code doesn't work for D2007 or earlier versions, no overloaded constructor with WindowBits argument...

Comment: When trying this I get compile error on the 2nd parameter to TDecompressionStream.Create; it only accepts the 1st FileStream (remember D2007).  Suppressing 2nd parameter compiles.  But then it throws a "Error" (that is all it says) at DecompressionStream.Read

Comment: @MSchenkel probably this feature was added in later versions... Interestingly, I wrote my own TGZipDecompressionStream based on zlib. Can share it here, there is not much.

Comment: @MSchenkel it would require literally 2 lines of code to add gzip functionality to D2009 zlib by inheriting TCompressionStream/TDecompressionStream, but they made some fields private which requires to copy-paste some amount of code (not more then 50 lines).